# Bash command to search for any occurrence of phrase and return list of files and paths

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I'm looking for a simple bash command to search for a phrase in filenames, directory names, and within text of all files. It should return a list of files and directories. Ideally, I'd like the option to pipe it to a file like > myfiles.txt

Something like:

```
find 'my key phrase'
find 'my key phrase' > mylist.txt
```

would return:

```
/home/stuff/filewithmykeyphraseinit.txt
/home/stuff/a filename with my key phrase.doc
/home/stuff/a directory with my key phrase/another subdirectory/
```

**EDIT:**
I'm getting a lot of great suggestions I'm currently testing. One issue: is there a way to make these case-insensitive? I believe adding -i to grep works. How about find for filepaths/names? Also, I'd like to have the option to either send the output to a text file or to screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{ find . -name '*my key phrase*' ;
  grep -rl 'my key phrase' .     ;
} | sort -u > mylist.txt
```

Comment: To remove duplicates I'd change that to something like this: `{ find . -name '*my key phrase*'; grep -rl 'my key phrase' *; } | sed "s/^\.\///" | sort -u`

Comment: Better yet, `{ find . -name '*my key phrase*'; grep -rl 'my key phrase' .; } | sort -u`.

Comment: This one is working well. I add i to grep, so grep -irl, to make it case insensitive. Is there an equivalent option for find?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, just specify you want to match file names and add wildcards to your pattern:

```
find -name '*my key phrase*' > mylist.txt
```

To search within the contents of files, use the grep command (with `-r` recursive option, or rgrep):

```
rgrep -l 'my key phrase' >> mylist.txt
```

Comment: But he wants to search within files as well.

Comment: @ezod: oh, true. I overlooked that!

Answer (score 0):

one command to do it all (using xargs and bash)

```
find | xargs -I {} bash -c '(([[ -f "{}" ]] && grep -l "my key phrase" "{}") || ([[ "{}" =~ "my key phrase" ]] && echo {}))'
```