# Convert my bash command into a bashrc function and pass argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I've got a sweet bash command to find key phrases in files and filepaths, [thanks to @ezod here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12865286/318090). I'm trying to turn it into a function in my bashrc, but it doesn't generate the same result. I'm guessing it's related to back-to-back curly brackets that I need to escape or use an alternative method?

**Works:**

```
{ find . -name '*keyword*'; grep -irl 'keyword' .; } | sort -u
```

**Does not work in bashrc:**

```
function findit() {
  { find . -name '*$1*';
    grep -irl '$1' .;
  } | sort -u
}
export -f findit

$ findit keyword
```

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I've posted the final bashrc function here: https://gist.github.com/3886154

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash won't substitute variables in single quotes.  Try this:

```
function findit() {  
  { find . -name "*$1*";  
    grep -irl "$1" .;  
  } | sort -u  
}  
export -f findit
```

Comment: Note that the `;` after grep is not necessary.  It would only be required if the new-line were removed.